# PHP: creating select options from MYSQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create multiple select dropdowns from MYSQL database!

basically I need to create select dropdowns based on the given sub-categories and put every `op_value` related to that `sub_cate_name` under the created dropdown menu as options.

at the moment, my code creates the dropdowns and select options BUT it will put them in separate select dropdwons and all over the place.

For example: if we have 2 `sub_cate_name` as `Apples` and 3 `op_value` as `Reds, Greens, Yellows` it will create 2 select dropdown menus and split them `op_value` which is (Reds, Greens, Yellows) as select options where ever it likes!

but i need it to make sure it creates 1 select dropdown as Apples and put ever op_value related to apples under the Apples dropdown as option!

This is code seems to have mind of its own as it works sometimes and it doesn't others!

this is the entire code:

```
$drops ="";

$sql44 ="SELECT * FROM drop_options WHERE sub_cat_name='$currentproduct'";

$query44 = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql44);
$productCount44 = mysqli_num_rows($query44);
if ($productCount44 > 0) 
{
    $op_name = '';
    $first = 0;

    while($row44 = mysqli_fetch_array($query44, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {


            $op_value = $row44["op_value"];

            if($op_name != $row44["op_name"])
            {
               if($first)
                {
                    $drops .='</select></div>';
                }

                $op_name = $row44["op_name"];

                $drops .='<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                <p class="margin-bottom-zero">'.$op_name.'</p>
                <select name="keyword[]" class="selectpicker">

                <option value="'.$op_value.'">'.$op_value.'</option>';
            }
            else
            {
                $drops .= '<option value="'.$op_value.'">'.$op_value.'</option>';
            }

            /*$first = 1;*/
            $first++;
    }
} 
else 
{
    $drops ='';
}
$drops .='</select></div>';
echo $drops;
```

Could someone please advise on this issue?

any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Okay, now i tried it this way and I can get the exact amount of the select drop downs created as it should:

```
if($db_conx->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db_conx->connect_error . ']');
};


// Perform queries
$sql45 = "SELECT DISTINCT op_name FROM drop_options WHERE sub_cat_name='Custom Booklets";
$result45 = $db_conx->query($sql45);

//echo '<li class="product-types">';


foreach ($result45 as $menu45)
{
    // echo "<li>".$menu["cat_name"];
echo '<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                <p class="margin-bottom-zero">'.$menu45["op_name"].'</p>
                <select name="keyword[]" class="selectpicker">';




     //echo "<ul>";
    $menu_title45 = $menu45["sub_cat_name"];

    $sql455 = "SELECT * FROM drop_options WHERE op_name='".$menu45["op_name"]."'";    

    $result455 = $db_conx->query($sq455);
    foreach ($result455 as $submenu455)
    {
        //echo "<li>".$submenu["sub_cat_name"]."</li>";

        echo '<option value="'.$submenu455["op_value"].'">'.$submenu455["op_value"].'</option>';
    }
     echo "</select>";
     echo "</div>";
}


//echo "</ul>";
$db_conx->close();
```

BUT i get no select options created at all Also i get this error:  `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in line 18`

and this is on line 18 : `foreach ($result45 as $menu45){`

any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: place your opening select outside the `while` loops

Comment: @Fred-ii- could you please elaborate?

Comment: you're using mysql resource object as an iterable which it isnt,you should `while` loop together with fetch function like `mysqli_fetch_array` as you did in first code

Comment: @Gal, but the first code doesn't work as it creates 1 select list for each mysql result and as I stated, it seems like it has mind of its own as it works for some and doesn't work for others! and i don't see any difference between the results that it works for and the ones that it doesn't!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you're code should look like-

```
    // Perform queries
    $sql45 = "SELECT DISTINCT op_name FROM drop_options WHERE sub_cat_name='Custom Booklets'";
    $result45 = $db_conx->query($sql45);

    //echo '<li class="product-types">';


    while ($menu45 = mysqli_fetch_array($result45,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        // echo "<li>".$menu["cat_name"];
        echo '<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
            <p class="margin-bottom-zero">'.$menu45["op_name"].'</p>
            <select name="keyword[]" class="selectpicker">';


        //echo "<ul>";
        $menu_title45 = $menu45["sub_cat_name"];

        $sql455 = "SELECT * FROM drop_options WHERE op_name='".$menu45["op_name"]."'";

        $result455 = $db_conx->query($sql455);
        while($submenu455 = mysqli_fetch_array($result455,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
        {
            //echo "<li>".$submenu["sub_cat_name"]."</li>";

            echo '<option value="'.$submenu455["op_value"].'">'.$submenu455["op_value"].'</option>';
        }
        echo "</select>";
        echo "</div>";
    }


    //echo "</ul>";
    $db_conx->close();
```

You may want to add `if` condition to check whether there are actually select options so you wont end up with an empty select.

Comment: that throws this error: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in line 13. and this is on line 13: while ($menu45 = mysqli_fetch_array($result45,MYSQLI_ASSOC))

Comment: i realised i was missing a ' .. omg... school boy error. let me try that now.

Comment: nope, that didn't work either! it just doesn't output anything! but with own code (the second one in my edit) i get 1 dropdown and it creates so many options... it basically puts the options for other op_names under the created select dropdown!

Comment: Because `foreach` iterate each value separately that's why I used `while`.about your issue I had a typo in second query call check it now. btw next time do more research I cant guess what is the issue, check your html and look for the output,then mention it here so I could know where it went wrong